# Get a shareable link of a file in our google drive using Colab notebook

Tags: python, url, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

could anyone please inform me how to automatically get a shareable link of a file in our google drive using Colab notebook?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `xattr` to get file_id

```py
from subprocess import getoutput
from IPython.display import HTML
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')  # access drive
# need to install xattr
!apt-get install xattr > /dev/null
# get the id
fid = getoutput("xattr -p 'user.drive.id' '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/R.ipynb' ")
# make a link and display it
HTML(f"<a href=https://colab.research.google.com/drive/{fid} target=_blank>notebook</a>")
```

Here I access my notebook file at `/Colab Notebooks/R.ipynb` and make a link to open it in Colab.

Comment: Hmm... this appears to only work for notebook files. But using the url from J.K's approach below (https://drive.google.com/file/d/) seemed to work

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the suggested solution doesn't work. So I replaced the colab URL with "https://drive.google.com//file/d/"

Below what I used:

```
def get_shareable_link(file_path):
  fid = getoutput("xattr -p 'user.drive.id' " + "'" + file_path + "'")
  print(fid)
  # make a link and display it
  return HTML(f"<a href=https://drive.google.com/file/d/{fid} target=_blank>file URL</a>")

get_shareable_link("/content/drive/MyDrive/../img_01.jpg")
```

Comment: This worked but for some files that I have just created I got "local-d8' as the fid, and could not follow the link.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70887780/1855988

Comment: What is the definition of getoutput?

Comment: @JohnTargaryen, check this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getoutput

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the [documentation](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=7taylj9wpsA2) you can see a section that explain how to list files from Drive.

Using that and reading the [documentation of the library used](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filelist.html), I've created this script:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

files = drive.ListFile().GetList()
for file in files:
  keys = file.keys()
  if 'webContentLink' in keys:
    link = file['webContentLink']
  elif 'webViewLink' in keys:
    link = file['webViewLink']
  else:
    link = 'No Link Available. Check your sharing settings.'

  if 'name' in keys:
    name = file['name']
  else:
    name = file['id']

  print('name: {}  link: {}'.format(name, link))
```

This is currently listing all files and providing a link to it.

You can then edit the function to find a specific file instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, it helps!
But how if I wanna go to a specific folder or file instead?

Comment: You can use the `{'q': QUERY}` parameter to filter the files so their `parent` property is the ID of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

get_output wasn't defined for me in the other answers, but this worked instead, after doing the drive.mount command: (test.zip needs to point to the right folder and file in your Drive!):

```
!apt-get install -qq xattr
filename = "/content/drive/My\ Drive/test.zip"
# Retrieving the file ID for a file in `"/content/drive/My Drive/"`:
id = !xattr -p 'user.drive.id' {filename}
print(id)
```