# Get shareable link of Google Drive files in a specific folder

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I've been trying to apply the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959636/9640238), adapting from the [PyDrive documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filelist.html). What I want is to work on files in a specific folder, not get a list of all files in my Drive (which contains thousands). So I've tried:

```py
files = drive.ListFile({'q': "'myfolder' in parents"}).GetList()
```

where `myfolder` is the name of the folder I want to get this list from. However, this returns an HTTP 404 error. Replacing `myfolder` with `root` works (per [Google's example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files#query_string_examples)), but take ages (so my syntax is correct, but I probably misunderstand what `parents` represents).

Can anyone help?

Comment: So you are interested in listing all the files (children) of a folder am I right? Maybe using ```children.list()``` would solve your question, check out a simple implementation of it [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list#examples) and its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list) and let me know if this solved your issue for formalising it into an answer :D

Comment: Mmmmh... I guess that could work, but I would have hoped for getting a list of [`GoogleDriveFile`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/pydrive.html#pydrive.files.GoogleDriveFile) objects from which I can then grab the shareable link directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually was nearly there: I needed to pass the folder ID instead of the name in the query:

```py
files = drive.ListFile({'q': "'folder_id' in parents"}).GetList()
```

From there, I get a collection of dictionaries from which it's easy to get the file name (`title` key) and shareable link (`alternateLink`).