# Uploading huge amount of files via Google Drive File Stream

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I'm making a PoC app that will deal with uploading a vast amounts of data to Google Drive via their File Stream app (DFS).

The subject of my concern is how the File Stream deals with uploading the files specifically. Upon my research, I gathered that when you copy the file to the Google Drive (I mean the file system, typically `G:`), it is actually copied to the application's cache (typically `%LOCALAPPDATA%/Google/DriveFS`), where it sits so the app can do all the uploading. That's fine, and it is also logical that when you want to copy, say, 100 GB of data while having only 50 GB of disk space available it will scream for more disk space. However, *I still want to upload these 100 GB*. Obviously, the solution is to split it into chunks and then copy them accordingly, but here is my question: how will I be able to know if the DFS finished uploading the previous chunk, so I can then copy another?

I made some experiments with uploading two ~2.5 GB files, starting the upload with a couple of minutes interval, so that I can inspect the DFS cache's size and it roughly matched the expected: before anything it was a couple of MB, after I copied the first it rose up by about 2.5 GB, after the second it rose again by the similar amount. Everything as expected. Now, I anticipated that after it was done with uploading the first file, the cache would shrink down again by the file's size, but to my surprise - nothing changed. It stood adamant, even after the second file finished. So that's where my question comes from - How would I go with uploading the data chunk by chunk? I really, really don't want to call the GDrive API to see if the files were uploaded; I'm using the DFS so that I don't have to include any authorization mess into that.

Any insight will be helpful. Oh, and I'm developing this is Python, but this is not entirely relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating and some trial and error I came up with the solution that works. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52107704/10834970) answer, I copy a chunk of files (say, 10 of them), and them periodically check their **md5 checksum** property on the DFS to compare with the locally calculated one, until all the files from the chunk checks:

```py
from hashlib import md5
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy2
from time import sleep


def file_checksum(file_path: Union[Path, str]) -> str:
    hash_md5 = md5()
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()


file = Path("C:/example.tst")
checksum = file_checksum(file)
dst = Path("G:/My Drive") / file.name
copy2(file, dst)
print("Started uploading", end="", flush=True)
while Path(f"{dst}:user.drive.md5").read_text() != checksum:
    print(".", end="", flush=True)
    sleep(1)
print("Uploaded!")
```