# Get google drive file ID from google colab

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'm trying in google colab to get the file ID of a file stored on my google drive.

When the file is created by a function inside google colab, I get a file ID in the form of "local-xxx" instead of the actual file ID. When the file is manually uploaded to google drive, I get the correct ID.

Could you please help me fix this? Posting my code below

```
  image_drive_url = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/"+file_name+".png"
  image_id = getoutput("xattr -p 'user.drive.id' '%s'" % image_drive_url) 

  print(image_id)
```

prints: local-702 instead of the actual file ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439810/get-google-drive-files-links-using-drive-file-stream/70887780#70887780) to a related question.

It contains the implementation of a workaround based on the following observation (from another answer in the same thread):

> Note: If you are using this in some type of script that is creating
> new files/folders and quickly reading the 'user.drive.id' afterwards,
> be aware that it can take many seconds for the "real" file id to be
> generated. If you read the value of 'user.drive.id' and it starts with
> 'local', this means that it has not yet generated an actual file id.
> In my opinion, the best way to deal with this is to create an
> asynchronous loop that sleeps between checks, and then returns the
> file id once it no longer starts with 'local'.

ps. I would rather post this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep points yet ;-)